# Why is this cookie not being deleted using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm stumped at this situation. I have a cookie with the following information:

```
Name: sessionid
Value: *redacted*
Path: /
Domain: localhost
```

I try to delete it with the following code in the `Console`:

```js
document.cookie = "sessionid=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/;domain=localhost"
```

But after I click the refresh button in the `Application` tab, it seems to have had no effect, and the cookie still has the same value as before.

What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an `HttpOnly` secure cookie that can not be read, modified or deleted using client side javascript

Comment: Thank you, that explains it.